# modulo version of the quadratic formula and Euler's criterion

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Use the modulo version of the quadratic formula and Euler's criterion to decide if the following has a solution or not.

$2x^2+5x+8 \equiv 0\pmod{37}$

I'm not sure how I would use what was being asked of me to decide if this has a solution or not, but I have came to the conclusion that it does not, because I plugged in every possible answer $0-36$, and none of them were congruent to zero.

The way people have answered the question, isn't exactly the way I need.  I have made some progress, but I'm not exactly sure how to finish:

$2x^2+5x+8 \equiv 0\pmod{37}$

$x^2+21x+4\equiv0\pmod{37}$

$x^2+58x+841\equiv837\pmod{37}$

$(x+29)^2\equiv23\pmod{37}$

I know that if $p$ is an odd prime and $p$ doesn't divide $a$, then $x^2\equiv a\pmod{p}$ has a solution or no solution depending on whether $a^\frac{p-1}{2}\equiv 1  \space\space \text{or}\space -1\pmod{p}$.

This is where I get stuck.  Can someone help me from here?  I have a feeling this problem has no solutions, so could someone also explain to me what to do if a problem like this did have solutions.

Comment: The OP (who has not been active in nearly nine years now) got to the point of needing to compute $23^{18}$ mod $37$. It suffices to complete the calculation as

$$23^{18}\equiv(-14)^{18}=196^9\equiv11^9=1331^3\equiv(-1)^3=-1\pmod{37}$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the quadratic congruence $ax^2+bx+c\equiv 0\pmod{p}$, where $p$ is an odd prime. Multiplying through by $4a$, we obtain the equivalent congruence 
$$4a^2x^2+4abx+4ac\equiv 0\pmod{p},$$
which, by completing the square, can be rewritten as 
$$(2ax+b)^2\equiv b^2-4ac\pmod{p}.\tag{$1$}$$
So in order for the original congruence to be solvable, $b^2-4ac$ must be a square modulo $p$.  Conversely, but we will not need this, if $b^2-4ac$ is congruent to a square modulo $p$, then we can use $(1)$ to solve the original congruence, in a manner which is essentially the Quadratic Formula.

In our case, $4b^2-4ac=25-64=-39\equiv -2\pmod{37}$. So we want $-2$ to be a quadratic residue of $37$. By Euler's Criterion, which you have been asked to use, this is the case precisely if 
$$(-2)^{\frac{37-1}{2}}\equiv 1\pmod{37}.$$
Since we are calculating an even power, we don't need to worry about the minus sign.  Note that $2^5\equiv -5\pmod{37}$, so $2^{10}\equiv 25\pmod{37}$, and therefore $2^{13}\equiv 200\equiv 15\pmod{37}$. It follows that $2^{18}\equiv -75\equiv -1\pmod{37}$, and therefore by Euler's Criterion $-2$ is not a quadratic residue of $37$.  We could also have used the calculator, by computing $2^{18}$, and dividing by $37$: the remainder is not $1$.

You can get this in a simpler way. Since $-1$ is a QR of $37$, we find that $-2$ is a QR iff $2$ is. But $37$ has the shape $8k+5$, and $2$ is a QR of primes of the shape $8k\pm 1$, and a NR of primes of shape $8k\pm 3$.

Comment: bx+c i guess , and i guess QR is quadratic residue and NR - not quadratic residue????

Comment: Yes, fairly standard abbreviation,

Comment: first line should be bx+c , thank you very much Andre , good answer

Comment: : @talmudist: Thank you, I very much appreciate the opportunity to correct old typos/answers.   Like the name, am envious of the choice.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint** $\rm\bmod 37\:$ it has discriminant $\,-39\equiv -2\,$ which is not a square (by [Euler's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion)).

Recall: if a quadratic $\rm\,f(x)\in R[x]\,$ has a root in a ring $\rm R,$ then its discriminant $\rm\Delta\,$is a square in $\rm R.\,$ Said contrapositively, if the discriminant is not a square in $\rm R,$ then the quadratic has no root in $\rm R.\,$
The proof, by **completing the square**, works in any ring $\rm\,R\,$ (so in $ \mathbb Z/37 = $ integers mod $37$), viz.

$$\rm\ \ \ \ \ \color{#0a0}{4a}\,(a\,x^2\! + b\,x + c\, =\, 0)\ \Rightarrow\ (2a\,x+b)^2 =\, b^2\! - 4ac =: \Delta$$

Here we assume are rings are *commutative*. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4468139/242) for some concrete worked examples.

**Remark** $ $ Conversely if $\rm\,\Delta = d^2\,$ and $\rm\,\color{#0a0}{2a}\,$ is invertible [then the above arrow reverses](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3461547/242) and the roots of $\rm\,(2ax+b)^2= d^2\,$ are roots of $\rm\,4a\:\!f\,$ so roots of $\rm\,f\,$ (by cancelling $\:\!\color{#0a0}2\:\!$ and $\rm\:\!\color{#0a0}a),\:\!$  which yields the classical quadratic formula $\rm\,x = (-b\pm d)/(2a).\,$ In the OP we are working over  ring $\rm\, R = \Bbb Z_n,\,$ and [recall that](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2326680/242)  $\rm\,\color{#0a0}{2a}\,$ is invertible in $\Bbb Z_n\! \!\iff\! \rm\gcd(2a,n)=1\iff n\,$ is odd and coprime to $\,\rm a.$

**Beware** that generally a modular quadratic can have more than $2$ roots, e.g. $\,x^2\equiv 1\,$ has the roots $\,x\equiv \pm1,\pm3\pmod{\!8},\,$ and we can find them all [by CRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3250900/242). In fact  [iterating the Factor Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2049882/242) easily shows that a commutative ring is an integral domain iff nonzero polynomials over it have no more roots than their degree.

When learning (modular) arithmetic in new rings it is *essential* to keep in mind that, like above, any proofs from familiar *concrete* rings (e.g. $\mathbb Q,\mathbb R,\mathbb C)$ will generalize to *every* ring if they are *purely ring theoretic*, i.e. if the proof uses only *universal* ring properties, i.e. laws that hold true in *every* ring, e.g. commutative, associative, distributive laws. Thus many familiar identities  (e.g. Binomial Theorem, difference of squares factorization) are *universal*, i.e. hold true in every ring.  The above implication - that a solvable quadratic over $\rm\:\!R\:\!$ has a discriminant being a square in $\rm\:\!R,\:\!$ used only commutative ring laws so it remains true in every commutative ring.  But we need further hypotheses ($\rm R\,$ is a domain and  $\,\rm\color{#0a0}{2a}\,$ invertible) in order to go further and obtain the quadratic formula and a proof that those are the only roots.

This is one of the great benefits provided by axiomatization: abstracting the common properties of familiar number systems into the abstract notion of a ring allows us to give *universal* proofs of ring theorems. It is not necessary to reprove these common ring theorems every time we studies a new ring. Such duplication occurred frequently before rings were axiomatized and the [axiomatic method](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Axiomatic_method) became well-known.

Comment: So if the discriminate has a square, for a quadratic congruence, it has a solution?

Comment: Here we need the *converse:* $\rm\,f(x)\,$ has discriminant D nonsquare in $\Bbb Z/37\,$ $\Rightarrow$ $\rm\,f(x)\,$ has no root $\in \Bbb Z/37.\:$ Conversely, if if D is a square, then you can apply the quadratic forumula to obtain a root *presuming* that twice the leading coefficient is invertible. Howver, the quadratic formula needn't give *all* roots when the ring is not a domain, e.g. mod $8$ note $\rm\: x^2 = 1\:$ has *four* roots $\rm\: x = \pm 1,\ \pm 3.\ \ $

Comment: Note:  above we assume our ring $\,\rm R\,$ is commutative with $1.\ \ $

Answer (score 3):

The modular version of the quadratic formula is, for all practical purposes, just the quadratic formula (provided twice the coefficient of $x^2$ is relatively prime to the modulus). As usual, you wind up looking at $b^2-4ac$, which here is $5^2-(4)(2)(8)=25-64=-39$. Since we're working modulo $37$, we can replace that $-39$ by $-2$ or by $35$, if we find it convenient. If $-39$ is a quadratic residue (a "square") modulo $37$, the congruence has solutions; if not, not. So, presumably you have some way to work out whether $-39$ is a quadratic residue modulo $37$ --- that should be where Euler's criterion comes in.