# Quadratric modular equation

Tags: modular-arithmetic, quadratics

I need to find all numbers

\begin{equation}
6x^2 + 2x \equiv 20 \pmod{513}
\end{equation}

and I'm having a trouble since 513 is not prime number

I tried looking for roots but i end up with

\begin{equation}
2(x+2)(3x-5) \equiv 0 \pmod{513}
\end{equation}

which lead to nothing in this case.

I also wanted to somehow find a square foirmual of my equation to make it a bit easier but I

failed doing it and now I'm running out off ideas how to solve it.Any help would be much

appreciated.

I found way to write it down as

\begin{equation}
(6x+1)^2 \equiv 121 \pmod{513}
\end{equation}
and then

\begin{equation}
6x \equiv 6 \pmod{19}\\
6x \equiv 11 \pmod{19}\\
6x \equiv 12 \pmod{27}\\
6x \equiv 13 \pmod{27}\\
\end{equation}

but after solving it I get bad answers so is my approach close to right one?

Comment: Can you explain how you found $2(x+2)(3x+5)\equiv 0$ and $(6x+1)^2\equiv 121$? They both seem suspicious to me.

Comment: sure I multiplied both sides by 6 and got
36x^2+12x-120=0, then 
(36x^2+12x+1)-121=0, 
(6x+1)^2=121

Comment: Unfortunately you are not allowed to multiply by $6$ because $6$ is not invertible modulo $513$. Rather, you are (of course) allowed, but the equation you get is no longer equivalent to the original (you will get more solutions than the original equation).

Comment: oh yes you're right ,but then right now I don't really know what to do in that case

Comment: You can apply the CRT for $19$ and $27$.

Comment: It is not quite over since the leading coefficient is not invertible mod $27$.

Comment: I dont think so because there isn;t any alternate form to wrote it down as square

Comment: You do have $x=5\pmod{3^3}$ and $x=9,13\pmod{19}$. Apply chinese residue theorem.

Comment: Also, in your derivation of $(6x+1)^2\equiv 121$, there seems to be a mistake, you get $6x$ and not $12x$ in the quadratic expression, after multiplying by $6$. Unless there is a typo in the original equation?

Comment: i made a mistake it should be 2x instead of one

Comment: @Piquito how do you know that x=5 mod 27 and 9,13 are mod 19?

Comment: The same CRT method in the dupe works here: simply CRT combine the obvious roots $\,{−2}\bmod 27\,$ 
 with the roots $\,{−}2,\,8\bmod 19\ \ $

Comment: @Cap We *can* apply the quadratic formula if we *also* scale the modulus by $6$ (as explained in the 2nd linked dupe), so $\bmod 6\cdot 513\!:\ x\equiv \dfrac{-1\pm\sqrt{11^2}}6,\,$ with    $\,s = \sqrt{11^2}\equiv \pm11,\pm 961$  must be $\color{#c00}{{-}11,+961}\,$  by $\,s\equiv 1\pmod{\!3}$ for $3$ to cancel from the denom (so the fraction exists). We compute the nontrivial sqrt $\,s=961$ by CRT solving $\,s\equiv 11\pmod{\!38},\ s\equiv -11\pmod{\!81}.\,$ Finally $\bmod 513\!:\ x\equiv (-1+\{\color{#c00}{-11,961}\})/6 \equiv -2,160\ \ $